# Calendar App on MacOS Won't Sync After 5PM

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I have a rather odd problem with my mac... None of my 4 Google calendars (2 gsuite, 2 normal) sync properly after around 5PM. The Calendar UI only shows The server responded with an error.

I've tried:

- Clearing the calendar app cache following [this procedure](https://www.wikihow.com/Clear-the-iCal-Cache)
- Removing and re-adding these accounts entirely
- Entirely removing ~/Library/Caches
- NVRAM and SMC reset
- Upgrading the entire system from Catalina to Mojave

The only clue I have is this line from logs is:

```
CoreDAVPropFindTask failed: Error Domain=CoreDAVHTTPStatusErrorDomain Code=403 "(null)"
```

But still no love. Does anyone have any ideas? This is one of the more bizarre computer problems I've ever had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a fault on google’s end affecting macos / google calendar integration.

The relevant google support thread is [here](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/98473879?hl=en)

Comment: Curious of the steps listed on the google link worked for anyone.  Followed the steps to clear the cache and reset permissions and it somehow got worse?

Comment: @sedavidw no, the steps do nothing for the current issue. imo they should be removed from the google support thread.